# Cannot recursive copy a hidden directory - UNIX

Tags: macos, bash, unix

I'm currently trying to recursive copy a hidden directory using this command

```
cp -r ../openshiftapp/.openshift .
```

It is not working.. what can be wrong?

Comment: I just tried it and it worked fine.

Comment: I now tried `cp -R ../openshiftapp/.openshift .` and it worked. Thanks though.

Comment: Is `.openshift` a file or a directory? Recursive copy only makes sense for a directory, otherwise there's nothing to recurse into.

Comment: sorry, directory. I edit it. I ran `cp -R ../openshiftapp/.openshift .` and it worked.

Comment: Are you doing ls -ltra in your current directory? to see the hidden file? What's the error if any. Otherwise, it'll copy fine. If it's a file, you don't need -r to copy (recursively). If it's a folder, then -r or -R will work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On OS X you should use `-R` rather than `-r`. The man page (on Snow Leopard 10.6.8) says:

> Historic versions of the cp utility had a `-r` option.  This implementation supports that option; however, its use is strongly discouraged, as it does not correctly copy special files, symbolic links, or fifo's.

Comment: Great! didn't know that.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The recursive option for the `cp` command would be used on directories, not files. The documentation states:

```
-R, -r, --recursive
          copy directories recursively
```

The [OSX docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cp.1.html) have more info, but don't suggest that the option can be used with files. Instead, it still mentions their use for copying directory contents:

```
  -R    If source_file designates a directory, cp copies the directory and the entire subtree connected
           at that point.  If the source_file ends in a /, the contents of the directory are copied rather
           than the directory itself.  This option also causes symbolic links to be copied, rather than
           indirected through, and for cp to create special files rather than copying them as normal files.
           Created directories have the same mode as the corresponding source directory, unmodified by the
           process' umask.

           In -R mode, cp will continue copying even if errors are detected.

           Note that cp copies hard-linked files as separate files.  If you need to preserve hard links, consider using tar(1), cpio(1), or pax(1) instead.
```

Comment: Your quote is from the GNU cp man page, not OS X.

Comment: Updated response to include OSX-related info. It still holds true that the `-R` option is to be used with directories.

Comment: If the source is a file, I believe the recursive option is simply ignored, and it copies the file normally. But that's irrelevant to this question, because he's copying a directory.